# Replacing an open-ended HTML regex match in Sublime Text

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, regex-negation, boost-regex

I've been doing a lot of finding and replacing in Sublime Text and decided I needed to learn RegEx. So far, so good. I'm no expert by any means, but I'm learning quickly.

The trouble is knowing how to replace open-ended HTML matches.

For example, I wanted to find all `<button>`s that didn't have a `role` attribute.
After some hacking and searching, I came up with the following pattern ([see in action](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?3632n)):

`<button(?![^>]+role).*?>(.*?)`

Great! Except, in the code base I'm working in, there are tons of results.
How do I do about replacing the results safely by injecting `role=button` at the end of `<button`, just before the closing `>` in the opening tag?

**Desired results**
Before: `<button type="button">`
After: `<button type="button" role="button">`

Before: `<button class="btn-lg" type="button">`
After: `<button class="btn-lg" type="button" role="button">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture everything before the ending `>` and put it back, before the insertion of `role=button`:

```
<(button(?![^>]+role).*?)>
```

This captures everything in the tag.

Replace by:

```
<$1 role="button">
```

The `$1` contains what the first regex captured.

See the [updated regexr](http://regexr.com?3632t).